# Select and count array keys in athena

Tags: sql, amazon-athena

I have many rows of data that represent events in my database. Each row has a column "payload" that contains an array of keys and values. I can easily parse for a value by using

```
Select
payload.keyname
from Database
```

But I am trying to get a list and count of all the keys that appear in a given day.

```
|                   payload                               |    
|{id=a, gameid=x, gametype=1, sponserid=null}             |
|{id=b, gameid=y, gametype=2, action=jump, sponserid=null}|
|{id=c, gameid=z, action=jump, sponserid=null}            |
```

Desired Output

```
|    Key  |Count|
|id       |  3  |
|game     |  3  |
|gametype |  2  |
|action   |  2  |
|sponserid|  2  |
```

Is there some method to query an array for keys easily? Such as

```
Select
payload.*, count(*)
from Database
group by payload.*
```

Comment: What is the type of `payload.keyname`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `map_keys` function to extract keys from `payload` and unnest on top of it.

```
select key, count(1) as count
from database.table, unnest(map_keys(payload)) as X(key)
group by 1
```

Comment: And this would work but it turns out the column is actually a row() type, and so it throws an error.

Comment: if the column is of row type then you can simply remove the UNNEST and cross join with the column

Answer (score 1):

You can use `cross join unnest`. The unnest will "unroll" the map and return a row for each map entry with key, value columns. If you want to count occurrences of each key you can group by key. For example

```
select key, count(*)
from mydb cross join unnest(payload) A(key, value)
group by 1
```

see [the docs](https://prestodb.io/docs/current/sql/select.html#unnest) for more info.

----- EDIT ----

If your column is already in row format you can do instead:

```
select payload.keyname, count(*)
from mydb cross join payload
group by 1
```

Comment: Thank you!
This seems like progress but I am getting an error saying 'the table payload doesn't exist', so I modified it:

select payload.*
from mydb cross join mydb.payload
group by 1

Which returns 'schema mydb does not exist'

Is there a specific format needed in Athena to get it to recognize the column Payload to be treated as its own table?

Comment: are you actually using "mydb" or the actual name of your table ("Database" in your original question?)

Comment: I am using the actual database name. It seems the specific issue is around how Athena is recognizing the column Payload when trying to use it for the cross join.